# Missing audio transcoding options under VLC for Mac

Tags: macos, audio, encoding, vlc-media-player

I'm following the [iPod Video Conversion Guide](http://wiki.videolan.org/IPod) for VLC (VideoLAN) v1.02 on a Mac. I've reached the section where I need to choose which audio transcoding option to use.

Both audio format options for iPod conversion, **mp4a** and **aac** are simply not in the list of selectable options. Does anyone know why, and if it's possible to add them?

Comment: ping.  anything further on this?  have you had any luck with the macports VLC, or tried an older release?

Comment: For the record, I couldn't get this to work, whether with the MacPorts version or the direct download from the VLC website. Would you be able to use Handbrake for your conversions? http://handbrake.fr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VLC compiles fine on my Mac 10.6 using MacPorts. You have also some lattitude to install variants and pimp your VLC, including the libraries you ask for.

```
$ port variants vlc
VLC has the variants:
   bonjour: Enable Bonjour support
   darwin_10: Platform variant, selected automatically
   dvb: enable DVB Program Specific Information support
   fribidi: Enable FriBidi Unicode support
     * requires osd
   full: Enable all variants except x11 and no_*
     * requires huge qt4 smb
   huge: Enable all variants except x11, qt4, smb and no_*
     * conflicts with minimal
     * requires dvb fribidi live555 sdl shout speex svg vcd
   live555: Enable Live555 streaming media support
   macosx: Platform variant, selected automatically
   minimal: VLC Mac OS X minimal configuration
[+]mod: Enable MOD demuxer support
[+]mpc: enable Musepack Decoder library support
   no_dvd: disable DVD and DeCSS support
   no_ffmpeg: disable FFmpeg support
[+]osd: Enable onscreen display and TrueType font support
   qt4: Build using QT4 UI.  This will use qt4-x11 if +x11 and qt4-mac otherwise.
   sdl: Enable SDL/SDL-Image support
   shout: Enable Shoutcast support
   smb: Enable Samba 3 support
   speex: Enable Speex decoder support
   svg: Enable SVG support
[+]theora: Enable OggTheora support
[+]twolame: Enable MPEG Audio Layer 2 encoding
   vcd: Enable VCD support
   x11: Build support for X11
[+]x264: Enable H.264 en/decoding
```

so simply issue:

```
$ sudo port install vlc +huge
```

(and by updating / upgrading, you'll stay in sync with latest releases)

Answer (score 0):

Have you selected the proper container format (MP4) before trying to select an audio format?

I've also seen [this July discussion at the VLC forums](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=62240) about a missing AAC encoder.  VLC uses FFmpeg, which uses [FAAC (libfaac)](http://www.audiocoding.com/faac.html) for AAC encoding.  According to the forum thread, there are licensing issues which prevented the then-current VLC builds from including FAAC.  I can't confirm that this is still the case.  If this is the problem, you can [compile it yourself](http://wiki.videolan.org/OSXCompile) to get a build that provides the missing functionality.

Comment: I'm going to try this with MacPorts as soon as they've fixed a compilation error for the VLC package. Will be back with an update, thanks!